# Serving undefined when outputting JSON array values jQuery Salvattore

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to output array values into a `src` attribute using getJSON, using those values to plug in with the [Salvattore](http://salvattore.com/) plugin. I'm able to get the values via `console.log`, but when I try to input the values into my `function append`, I'm getting a the following error: 'http://localhost:9000/PRINT/undefined'. when I look at the Google dev console, I see that its trying this: 'Cannot GET /PRINT/undefined'. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/renevilla23/8caup3j9/)

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function append(title) {
  var grid = $('#columns')[0];
  var item = document.createElement('div');
  var h = '<div class="panel panel-primary">';
  h += '<div class="panel-body">';
  h += '<img src="';
  h += title;
  h += '" />';
  h += '</div>';
  h += '</div>';
  salvattore['append_elements'](grid, [item]);
  item.outerHTML = h;
}

var dataJson = "https://api.myjson.com/bins/2xtqy";
$.getJSON(dataJson, function (data) {
  $.each(data.printImages,function (k, v) {
    //console.log(v);
    append(v.title);
  });
});
```

**Console.log Output for `console.log(v);`**

```
http://reneinla.com/kris/images/print/2008-06_KZO_TEN_01.jpg
...
http://reneinla.com/kris/images/print/2008-06_KZO_TEN_05.jpg
```

this is what i want in the `src` attribute

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
 <h1 class="col-xs-12">Example</h1>

 <div data-columns="" id="columns">
  <div></div> 
  <div></div> 
  <div></div>          
 </div>
</div>
```

**QUESTIONS**

1. Why is are the values serving '/PRINT/undefined' when they're being outputted if they're being served properly with `console.log`?
2. How do I get the values that are correctly outputted in `console.log(v);` into the `src` attribute?

I'm learning and would highly appreciate any insight! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're outputting `v`:

```
//console.log(v);
// -----------^
```

...and seeing `http://reneinla.com/kris/images/print/2008-06_KZO_TEN_01.jpg`, which suggests that `v` is a string. But then you're passing `v.title` into your function:

```
append(v.title);
// -----^^^^^^
```

`v.title` will be `undefined` if `v` is a string.

Perhaps you should pass in what you're logging, `v`.

Comment: so do I have to parse `v` using parseJSON before I pass it to v.title?

Comment: As far as I can tell from your question, you just pass `v` to `append`. You haven't quoted the JSON response you're looping through, so I can't say more certainly than that.

Comment: It worked! Many thanks for the advice and suggestion!